# Read a file starting from the second line in python

Tags: python, file, io

I use python and I don't know how to do.

I want to read lots of lines in files. But I have to read from second lines. All files have different lines, So I don't know how to do.

Code example is that it read from first line to 16th lines. 
But I have to read files from second lines to the end of lines.
Thank you!:)

```
with open('filename') as fin:
  for line in islice(fin, 1, 16):
    print line
```

Comment: Read the first line and discard it. Then read the rest of the file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to call `next` and discard the first line:

```
with open('filename') as fin:
    next(fin) # cast into oblivion
    for line in fin:
        ... # do something
```

This is simple and easy because of the nature of `fin`, being a generator.

Answer (score 4):

```
with open("filename", "rb") as fin:
    print(fin.readlines()[1:])
```

Comment: While this code would work to solve OPs Problem, it would be much better if you included a minimal amount of information along with it. Chances are that others reading this question might not be familiar with everything in the code or the idea behind it

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for [islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

> itertools.islice(iterable, stop)
> itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])
>
> Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable. If start is non-zero, then elements from the iterable are skipped until start is reached. Afterward, elements are returned consecutively unless step is set higher than one which results in items being skipped. **If stop is None, then iteration continues until the iterator is exhausted, if at all**; otherwise, it stops at the specified position. Unlike regular slicing, islice() does not support negative values for start, stop, or step. Can be used to extract related fields from data where the internal structure has been flattened (for example, a multi-line report may list a name field on every third line).

I think you can just tell it to start at the second line and iterate until the end.  e.g.

```
with open('filename') as fin:
    for line in islice(fin, 2, None):  # <--- change 1 to 2 and 16 to None
        print line
```