# CSV reader with .txt file

Tags: python-3.x

My input file has garbage text at the beginning.  Actual data begins at line 16.  How can I begin reading at a particular line?

```
with open('c:/sw_mac_addr/test.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

f.close()
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this existing question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270638/read-a-file-starting-from-the-second-line-in-python

Comment: remove `f.close()` - that is done by `with open()...:` on leaving its scope. Use `for _ in range(16): next(reader)` before your loop to discard first 16 lines

Comment: Thank you!  I'm also trying to find out how to just print desired columns.  Is this content = ?